# Storage System for NFC Cards

Tags: tags, storage, nfc, rfid, ndef

At the moment I'm exerpimenting and researching with and about NFC. 
I use Mifare 1k Tags and I recorgnized that there are Sime Blocks/Sectors where I'm not allowed to Write on. I've found an Application that writes Data to Tag, this Application automatically skips those forbidden sectors. If I write a Application with NFC Tags by myself I dont want to declare the forbidden Sectors by Hand, so no Specific Tagtype is required.

So my Question is: Is there some Sort of Storage Systems for NFC Tags, like NTF for SSD/HDD?

Maybe someome knows something about it or could give me a Tip what i should Search for.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheets for the tags detail the storage system https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf

The tags will usually also conform to one of the NFC Forums specifications (most available http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/ )

A lot will also be able to store NDEF data (the spec for that is https://github.com/haldean/ndef/tree/master/docs )